# how to execute a code after certain time php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem which I am not sure possible with `php` or not , may be I need `javascript` for this . problem is when user login i am saving current time to `session` and i want to fire a pop exact 10 minutes later if condition are matched .

```
$dbdate = strtotime("+1 minutes",$_SESSION['logintime']);

$timwnow=date("H:i:s"); 

if (strtotime($timwnow) == $dbdate) {

  if(isset($checkno_wq) || isset($checkno_ap) || isset($Appcount) || 
 isset($followup_count) || isset($count_request) || isset($count_self_study) || isset($countBroadcast) || isset($perform_count) || isset($qa_count) || isset($attendance_count) || isset($coach_count) || count($pre_appoverd) > 0)
{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout( function() { $("#notificationModal").modal("show");
  }, 10000);
</script>';
}
```

}

may any one help me on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use a cron to execute a script at a specific time. Using your condition (`if (strtotime($timwnow) == $dbdate) {`), you'd have to load the page exactly when the times match for the code to run, might want to consider changing it to `>=`.

Comment: cron job is not the solution , because its need to display after 10 minutes of user login and user can login any time

Comment: use that in js by the **setTimeout(showPop,1000);** : this code mean that after 1 second n call the function showPop only  one time .

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI how can i know php condition matched or not , or if user reloaded page

Comment: " how can i know php condition matched or not " ...harcoded the value generated by PHP into the JS function. Your PHP code can be used to change what JS is sent to the browser. You know what time the user logged in. That means you can use that value to amend the JavaScript, and make the timeout happen ten minutes after that time. It might be 10 minutes from now (the first time the user loads the page) or it might be 10 seconds from now (if the user re-loaded the page afterwards).

Comment: yes , that true , so you can go using this solution , when  user is logged , save the current date into session storage , and another variable  nammed **popAlreadyshowed** (boolean) set in to default false, so here if the user reload the page , the data in storage session is always available , so you can check if the 10 minute has been already passed and **popAlreadyShowed** is false , show the pop and make **popAlreadyShowed** to true , here if the user reload the page , it will not show another time the pop .

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI how this event is run , with js , if possible please provide the code thanks

Comment: use crontab script

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the PopUp? You know that javascript can be manipulated easy? If it has any security implications you need to make sure it is checked on the server side too!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement this using javacript.

Here is the point , is that after loggin , store two variable :

The current date when user logged in , call it **logged_time**

Another variable to check if the pop is already showed , call it : **pop_already_showed**

```
localStorage.setItem('logged_time', new Date());
localStorage.setItem('pop_already_showed', false);
```

> Notice : you have to check if the looged_time key is not set to store
>   the new date , if not , when reloading the page it will always set
>   with new date and you can never detect if 10 minutes has been passed
>   or not in case of the user reload the page .

```
if (localStorage.getItem("logged_time") === null) {
      localStorage.setItem('logged_time', new Date());
}
```

The function that show the pop seems to be like the code bellow :

```
function showPop(){
   var rightnow = new Date();
   var diff = Math.abs(rightnow-localStorage.getItem('logged_time'));
   var min = Math.floor((diff/1000)/60);
   if(min>=10 && localStorage.getItem('pop_already_showed') ){
     localStorage.setItem('pop_already_showed', true);
     // add you code that show the pop here
   }
}
```

And finnaly , call the function with setTimeout

```
 setTimeout(function() {
    showPop();
}, 1000*60*10);
```

Hope that help you .

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
localStorage.setItem('logged_time', new Date();
localStorage.setItem('pop_already_showed', false);

  function showPop(){
   var rightnow = new Date();
   var diff = Math.abs(rightnow-localStorage.getItem('logged_time'));
   var min = Math.floor((diff/1000)/60);
   if(min>=10 && localStorage.getItem('pop_already_showed') ){
     localStorage.setItem('pop_already_showed', true);

     $("#notificationModal").modal("show");     

   }
}
</script>

Comment: its not storing values in local storage

Comment: there is a missing **)** , don't copy paste code , u have to analyze at least . check now i update my response